# empty div height issue in skeleton framework?

Tags: html, css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

STRANGE, in skeleton framework if I remove the content from last two divs (out of three divs appearing in a row) and then try to map these two divs height with first div height, applying height:100% to html, body, parent and all these three/last two divs.

The height doesn't set proper to any element. Moreover height appears strangely different when viewed in browser (mozilla / chrome) with and without keeping open the 'inspect element' panel .

Can anybody explain, why this happen. And how height for empty div can be achieved in this case.

<------------------------------------------------->

<---------------------------------------------------->

@mamuz, I'm talking about the skeleton default code [html/css package] which one can be downloaded from download section of skeleton website i.e. http://www.getskeleton.com. I tried adding height attribute for three divs those appear bottom in the section next to each other in a row with heading 'About Skeleton', 'Three Core Principles' and 'Docs & Support' respectively.

I added following lines in layout css:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
 }

body {
  height: 100%;
 }

.main { <!--class name applied to container or parent div -->
  height: 100%;
 }

.first-child, .second-child, .third-child { <!--class name given two three divs from left to right-->
  height: 100%;
 }
```

Apart above code, I just made second and third div empty and left the text content in first div only. To see if second and third divs match to the height of first div.

Comment: Please give us html and css code, then you will retrieve support. I bet.

Comment: @mamuz, please see original post for answer of your question.

Comment: To make my question more clear, I've uploaded an html package at following url: http://www.2shared.com/file/bVpgHDUx/html.html

Open the html file in browser to see the issue. See Keeping open and close inspect element panel and scrolling the page.